# Prove that there exists the exact sequence (over Z) 0 → Z 2 →Z 4 → Z 4 → Z 2 → 0 .

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

$$ 0 \to \mathbb Z /2 \to \mathbb Z /4 \to \mathbb Z /4 \to \mathbb Z / 2 \to 0$$

To show that it is exact, I need $f : \mathbb Z / 2 \to \mathbb Z / 4$ monic, and $g : \mathbb Z /4 \to \mathbb Z /2$ epic.

homomorphism $f$ by $f([a])=[2a]$ , $[a]$ is in $\mathbb Z /2$ and $[2a]$ is in $\mathbb Z /4$ and homomorphism $g$ by $g([b]2)=[b]4$ .

when I take like that by finding all homomorphism between them, image of $f$ is not equal to kernel of $h : \mathbb Z /4 \to \mathbb Z /4$. Also image of $h$ is not equal to kernel of $g$.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: It looks like you've got the right $f$ and $g$. What homomorphisms are there from $\Bbb{Z}_4$ to itself? One of them fits! You can actually think if it via its kernel and image. After all, if $f:M\to N$ is *any* homomorphism, it is the composition
$$f:M\to M/\operatorname{Ker}(f)\to \operatorname{Im}(f)$$ with the first map the natural projection, and the second map the isomorphism from the First Isomorphism Theorem (aka Sophomore's Theorem).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. :) Of course,I tried to create an exact sequence by using image and kernel. Let's say E1: 0-> K -> M -> N->0 so we can get E2: 0-> imf -> M -> M/Ker(f) . ( f= K -> M, g=M -> N) in my question, for h=Z4->Z4 homomorphisms are f(a)=2a, f(a)=a or f(a)=3a. But ı need epic and also monic so f(a)=a or f(a)=3a can be used. But ı could not get eguality between image and kernel coz of homomoprhism h. If ı choose f(a)=2a, then ı get this equality but in this case , ı can not get epic homo.

Comment: But the kernel of $g$ is $\{\overline{0},\overline{2}\}$? This should be the image of $h$, so $h$ must not be an epimorphism. Similarly the image of your $f$ is $\{\overline{0},\overline{2}\}$, which should be the kernel of $h$, so $h$  cannot a monomorphism either.

Comment: Exactly! As you said and ı explained, if ı chose h(a)=2a,then kernel and image can be equal but for to obtain exact sequence, ı need epic and monic h. Thus ı m confused .

Comment: No. You absolutely don't need $h$ to be epi and mono to get an exact sequence. Why do you think that?

Comment: To get an exact sequence you need
$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=\operatorname{Ker(h)}$$ and
$$\operatorname{Im}(h)=\operatorname{Ker(g)}.$$ 
You already know what $f$ and $g$ must be, so you know $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ and $\operatorname{Ker(g)}$. THAT is the data $h$ must match with. No need for it to be epi/mono.

Comment: Another way to see the same thing. If $h$ is epi, then the kernel of $g$ must be everything. Therefore $g$ would have to be the zero map. Implying that the image of $g$ must be zero. This is a contradiction for $g$ being epi. Therefore $h$ cannot be epi. Similarly $h$ cannot be mono either.

Comment: Ah! For short exact, we need epic and monic, right ? Then everything is clean already.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Sounds like you worked it out. Well done.. Please consider posting your solutions as an answer (no pressure - your call). That way you get more feedback on the solution, and any lingering unclear points come to light.

Answer (score 0):

Homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/4$ can be defined as following:

Let $h(\bar{0})=h(\bar{2})=\bar{0}$, and $h(\bar{1})=h(\bar{3})=\bar{2}$.

It can be verified that $h$ is a homomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}/4$, which is a $\mathbb{Z}$ module.

And it's clear that Ker$(h)$=Im$(h)$=$\left\{\bar{0},\bar{2}\right\}$.